# Iterate/Loop over Shelve

Tags: python, python-3.x, shelve

How would one iterate the contents of a Shelve?

```
import Shelve
testShelve = Shelve.open("testShelve")
testShelve["key"] = "value"

for k in testShelve.keys():
    print(k)
```

Comment: The same way you would any other mapping (like a `dict`).

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html)? “A “shelf” is a persistent, dictionary-like object.” – Dictionary-like means you can use it like a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated above, the Shelve object is dictionary-like and can be used the same.
To print the keys and values of the testShelve object:

```
for key in testShelve:
    print(key, testShelve[key])
```